# Apache nifi gettwitter processor giving error 403 forbidden

Tags: apache-nifi

I just started using apache Nifi to create a flow from the getTwitter process and when I run the  process it keeps giving me error403 forbidden .Even [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49McG.png) after I gave the correct keys and secrets I tried watching multiple videos but none of them seem to help I generated new key values and retired but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Did you confirm and/or validate that the key values work using another tool to do the same thing? This way, you would be able to confirm that the values are correct and it’s just a NiFi issue.

Comment: i figured it out its because i need elevated access for twitter 1.1 so it wasn't working thanks for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check in with verifying that the Twitter API first, then work with NiFi. If Twitter API does work outside of NiFi, then it's a NiFi issue. If this works, then please feel free to accept this as the answer.